# "Залипает" кнопка в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Я вообще ничего не смыслю в программировании, кое как, по образцу, HTML коду, и одному вопросу тут - удалось сделать расширение на js. Оно добавляет кнопку в плеер модифицированного клиента Спотифая, и при нажатии открывает вкладку другого расширения. Вот его код:

```html
(function spotifyLyrics() {
    if (!Spicetify.LocalStorage) {
        setTimeout(spotifyLyrics, 1000);
        return;
    }

    function createLyricsButton() {
        const b = document.createElement("a");
        b.classList.add("button");
        b.innerText = "LYRICS  ";
        b.id = "lyricsButton"
        b.setAttribute('href','spotify:app:genius')
        b.draggable = false
        b.onclick = () => {
            if (document.getElementById("spotify:app:genius").style.display === "block") {
                closeNav();
            } else {
                openNav();
            }
        };
        return b;
    }

    const extraControlsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("extra-controls-container");
    extraControlsContainer[0].prepend(createLyricsButton()); // prepend = append before all

})();
```

Но есть проблема. Кнопка "залипает". Она подсвечивается нажатой до тех пор, пока я не нажму что нибудь другое, или в пустое место. При чем нажатия на панели плеера всё ещё оставляют её "залипшей". Как исправить? Если не совсем понятно, о чем я - [вот видео](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wpoP2PdkNgeQyg)

В общем, помогите пожалуйста, сам я тут совсем без знаний - никак не разберусь((

P.S. Если вдруг поможет, то вот HTML код соседней кнопки, которая работает номрально:

```
<button type="button" id="player-button-queue" name="queue" class="queue-button button button-queue spoticon-queue-16" data-ta-id="player-button-queue" data-bind="
            attr: {
              'data-drop-target': queueDropMimetypesUI,
              'data-drop-target-include-text': '',
              'data-tooltip': queueLabel,
              'data-tooltip-container': tooltipContainerSelector(),
              'aria-label': queueLabel,
              'aria-pressed': queueOpen() ? 'true' : 'false'
            },
            click: openQueue" data-interaction-target="open-queue-button" data-interaction-intent="open-queue" data-drop-target="text/x-spotify-tracks|text/x-spotify-episodes|text/x-spotify-albums" data-drop-target-include-text="" data-tooltip="Очередь" aria-label="Очередь" aria-pressed="true"></button>
```

Comment: Это element state `:focus` и/или `:active`, можешь дописать в код клика: [`.blur();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

Comment: Ничего не понял :c

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes